# regex grouping and decimal plus comma and Time

Tags: regex, string, automation, grouping

I need a regex for these String(s):

```
17 h 13 min - 43,1 km - Ankunft ca. 11:48

17 h 13 min - 1.443,1 km - Ankunft ca. 11:48

13 min - 431 m - Ankunft ca. 11:48

17 h - 3 km - Ankunft ca. 09:04
```

It has to be grouped in 3 Groups (routerarrivalin, routedistance, routeeta).

routearrival: 17 h 13 m 
routedistance: 43,1 km
routeeta: 11:48

I tried alot but I am constantly failing. What I have right now is this regex:

```
(?<routearrivalin>\d+?\s?h?\s?\d+?\s*m).+(?<routedistance>\d\d,\d\s[km|m]*).+(?<routeeta>\d\d:\d\d)
```

I cant filter the distance to match every possibility I have.
If someone is curious what I'm doing here: the string is the navigationinformation you get on a android phone from google maps. I want to split the string into mentioned variables to handle them with tasker and forward those to my display in the speedometer.

Comment: Can't you simply split on `-`?

Comment: Why not simply `^(?<routearrivalin>.+) - (?<routedistance>.+) - [^\d]*(?<routeeta>\d\d:\d\d)$` . [See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z34UBa/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took a little tweaking, but I have included some extra groups to handle the optional and changing parts and I think this is what you are looking for:
`(?<routearrivalin>([\d\s]+h)?([\d\s]*m)?)(in)?[\s-]+(?<routedistance>([\d.,]+\s+(km|m))).+(?<routeeta>\d\d:\d\d)`
You can see it here at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OtEQTq/3/) working with the example you have given